# Turn element of lxml.objectify back into XML

Tags: python, lxml

I use `lxml.objectify` to easily parse and work with an XML file. For auditing reasons, I have to save a derived object together with the originating XML code of the element.

```
root = lxml.objectify.fromstring(self.get_xml_data())

for i, elem in enumerate(root.elements):
    # create new database entry based on elem
    elem_obj.source_code = turn_elem_into_xml(elem)
```

How could I implement `turn_elem_into_xml`?

Comment: I downvoted you because you have not done even the most rudimentary research. In fact, you appear to be unaware of how to work with ordinary lxml objects.

Comment: I did actually spend quite a bit of time searching for the answer, as I usually do (just check my question/answer ratio). Sorry for not using the right google search terms this time around and not being that familiar with lxml...

Comment: There's an lxml website which prominently directs users to its tutorial, which in less than 10 minutes would have lead you to the answer, and a working knowledge of the library. It is possible to find pages without google.

Comment: @piquadrat I suggest reading [the `lxml.etree` tutorial.](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) It'll take you 15 minutes and it covers at least 60% or 70% of what most people want to do with `lxml.etree`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`lxml.etree.tostring`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#tostring)

```
In [21]: r = lxml.objectify.fromstring('<root><item>1</item><item>2</item></root>')

In [22]: lxml.etree.tostring(r.item)
Out[22]: '<item>1</item>'
```

Answer (score 1):

`lxml.objectify` elements are still normal elements. You can print them like any other, or turn them into strings, using `lxml.etree.tostring`.

Comment: @piquadrat: That's not how you deal with **any** lxml objects.

Comment: Yes, when someone tells you to use `.tostring()` don't use `str()`, use `.tostring()`.

Comment: @kindall: please check the timestamp of Marcin's edit. When I wrote my comment, his answer did not contain any reference to ``tostring``.